# Cuando usar los diferentes tipos de balanceadores AWS

Tags: aws

me podrían explicar ¿cuales son las diferencias entre los balanceadores de carga que tiene amazon?. Y ¿en qué casos podría usar cada uno de ellos?

Answer (score 1):

en este link podrás encontrar las diferencias y explicación: https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/details/#compare

¿Podrías dar más información acerca de cuáles son los requerimientos de tu aplicación?

Algunos servicios de AWS solo se pueden usar con Application Load Balancers, por ejemplo WAF (Web Application Firewall) solo puede usarse con ALB, así que esta es una ventaja de actualizar tu Classic Load Balancer a Application Load Balancer.

Otra de las ventajas del ALB es que puedes rutear tus request a diferentes “Target Groups” que son simplemente grupos de instancias de EC2. Por ejemplo si tu ruta es /app1, puedes rutear ese request al TargetGroup1 que pueden ser un grupo de instancias de capacidad menor-mediana, por otro lado, si tienes un request en tu ruta /app2, puedes rutear al TargetGroup2 y en este podrías tener otro tipo de instancias de EC2, tal vez una aplicación diferente a la que tienes en TargetGroup1. Con el Classic Load Balancer realmente todos los request van a cualquier instancia detrás del Load Balancer a comparación de el ejemplo que te doy con el Application Load Balancer.

Espero que estoy ayude a responder a tu pregunta.